# Cipher-text decryption using RSA theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The question is: Suppose you receive the cipher-text $C=47 \  with \ 0 \le C \lt n \ where \ n=55$, decrypt the message using the private key $(27,55)$.

I approached the problem by breaking it into two parts:
$
\begin{cases}
C \equiv 47^{27} \pmod{5} \\
C \equiv 47^{27} \pmod{11}
\end{cases}
$

After reducing the two congruences, to 
$
\begin{cases}
C \equiv 2 \pmod{5} \\
C \equiv 3 \pmod{11}
\end{cases}
$

I used modular arithmetic to obtain the answer that $C=12$. Since $ 0 \le 12 \lt 55$, does that mean my answer is correct? What methods can I use to verify whether my answer is right or wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method is fine and your conclusion is correct. However, you did a computation mistake as $47^{27}\equiv 9\not\equiv 3\pmod{11}$. The correct solution would then be $C=53$.

If you just want to *verify your solution*, simply use [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=47%5E27+mod+55) or similar software.

If you really want to use *methods* to check this, you could encrypt it again and check if it matches the cipher-text, because encrypting and decrypting are designed to be inverse functions. However you would need to know the public key. If it is not given as part of the task, you could compute it as the inverse of $27$ modulo $\varphi(55)$. In general, however, this is not that simple, which is good, since this difficulty is the whole point in RSA.

Another way to verify this, is to directly compute $47^{27}\bmod 11$. Using the  [square-and-multiply](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) technique, this is asymptotically faster than your method as yours requires the factorization of $N$, which is usually difficult to find – again this is the whole point of RSA.

To sum up, there is no more *efficient* way to verify your solution than to recalculate it, but if you just want to verify it for the sake of your homework grading, then there are computers that will happily compute this for you.

Comment: Thanks for the help! The guidance was very constructive for my sake